# How do you know if a UWP device has Chat/SMS Available?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, uwp

Is there a C# method to call to see if Chat/SMS is available on a Windows10 device?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the chat capabilities even on devices without a SIM card. Even Skype can also play the role of the default SMS app...

[This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-an-sms-message) is giving you a sample

```
private async void ComposeSms(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact recipient, string messageBody, StorageFile attachmentFile, string mimeType)
{
    var chatMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
    chatMessage.Body = messageBody;

    if (attachmentFile != null)
    {
        var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);

        var attachment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageAttachment(mimeType, stream);

        chatMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    var phone = recipient.Phones.FirstOrDefault<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPhone>();
    if (phone != null)
    {
        chatMessage.Recipients.Add(phone.Number);
    }
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(chatMessage);
}
```

To check if the message is a SIM message, you should take a look at the property [ChatMessage.IsSimMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessage.issimmessage)

```
var isSimMessage = chatMessage.isSimMessage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat "))
{     

}
```

Only if the method returns “true” the code inside it will be implemented, which indicates that SMS/Chat is available in this device.

Otherwise, your project will skip this part of code since the capability is unavailable in the device in case that your app may crash on these devices.

For more details, may check [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn949016?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).